# How to call helper method from a different lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, helper

I have lightning component A and lightning component B, in lightning component B there is a helper method X, how to call helper method X in lightning component B from the helper in lightning component A ?

(Please provide boilerplate code, thank you)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE, please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familair with the forum. Make sure you include waht you have tried and the problem you are facing with the code you wrote. If you are new to salesforce and lightning component development, then you should try [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home). thanks

Answer (score 14):

There are basically two ways to do this.

## Option 1: Extend a Component

You can extend an extensible component to share helper methods.

---

### BaseCmp

---

#### BaseCmp.cmp

```
<aura:component extensible="true">
</aura:component>
```

#### BaseCmpHelper.js

```
({
    helperMethod1: function() {
        // do stuff here
    }
})
```

---

### ChildCmp

---

#### ChildCmp.cmp

```
<aura:component extends="c:BaseCmp">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
</aura:component>
```

#### ChildCmpController.js

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.helperMethod1();
    }
})
```

---

Notes:

You can only extend one component. You can chain extensions together, but not recommended (e.g. Base -> Child1 -> Child2). This will have a performance impact.

Methods in child components with the same name as in the parent components will override the parent definition. Make sure all names are unique.

---

## Option 2: Call a Controller Method

You can use `aura:method` to call a controller method.

---

### utils

---

#### utils.cmp

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:method name="util1" action="{!c.callUtilMethod}" description="Calls util1">
    <aura:attribute name="aParam" type="String" />
  </aura:method>
</aura:component>
```

#### utilsController.js

```
({
  callUtilMethod: function(c,e,h) {
    return h.utilMethod1(c, e.getParam("arguments"));
  }
})
```

#### utilsHelper.js

```
({
  utilMethod1: function(c,args) {
    // do what you want here, then return...
    return someValue;
  }
})
```

---

This is called through an instance of the component.

### main

#### main.cmp

```
<aura:component>
  <c:utils aura:id="utils" />
  <!-- ... -->
</aura:component>
```

#### mainController.js

```
({
  someMethod: function(c,e,h) {
    var retVal = c.find("utils").util({ aParam: "Hello World" });
  }
})
```

---

You can also do asynchronous return values; define the method's parameter as a Function:

```
  <aura:method name="util1" action="{!c.callUtilMethod}" description="Calls util1">
    <aura:attribute name="callback" type="Function" />
  </aura:method>
```

Which you then call normally in your method:

```
({
  utilMethod1: function(c,args) {
    // do what you want here, then return...
    args.callback(returnValue);
  }
})
```

And would be called with a helper function:

```
({
  someMethod: function(c,e,h) {
    var retVal = c.find("utils").util({ callback: h.handleResponse.bind(h, c) }});
  }
})
```

Your response handler then looks like:

```
({
  handleResponse: function(c, retVal) {
    // Handle the response here
  }
})
```

---

Notes:

You can only call methods from components in your own namespace, or global methods from another namespace.

You need an instance of the component to call the helper. You cannot call it without first loading the component. This has implications on performance, so it should be used sparingly, and only as necessary.

---

There are better ways to share code, such as `ltng:require`. These two methods do work, but are not recommended. You can read more about all of this stuff in the documentation.